# Least Squares in Gaussian Noise

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian

I have the following linear model:
$$ y^{j} = w*x^{j} + e^{j} $$
where $e$ follows a normal distribution:
$$e = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(-n^{j})^2}{2\sigma }}$$

**I don't understand why the probability of the output sequence is:**

$$p(y^{j}|x^{j};w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(-(y^{j}- w*x^{j}))^2}{2\sigma }}$$

Please refer to this post for more information: www.dsplog.com/2012/01/15/least-squares-gaussian-noise-maximum-likelihood/

Answer (score 3):

It is because when $x^j$ and $w$ are known $e^j$ is the only random component. So $y^j$ is a simple linear transformation of $e^j$ and hence has a normal distribution with the same variance as $e^j$ but with a mean equal to $wx^j$.

Comment: thank you very much. However, I still don't understand why one can simply write the conditional distribution of y given x as the Gaussian distribution of the noise (with the noise being replaced by it's equivalent: n = y-wx) ?